# preg_replace_callback 内にて、if 文で条件分岐をした処理を書きたい

Tags: php

```
<?php
$content = <<<'EOD'
<pre class="prettyprint linenums">
<?php
if($hoge == 'hoge') {
  echo 'hoge!';
}
<span class="nocode">text</span>
</pre>
?>
EOD;
?>
```

といったソースコードを Wordpress に表示させるとき、ソースコードの部分を `htmlspecialchars` で実体参照変換して表示させる。
しかし、ソースコード内に注釈を入れる場合は `<span class="nocode"> 注釈 </span>` を利用したい。
`<span class="nocode"> 注釈 </span>` に対しては実体参照変換をせずに表示したい。
もしくは、`<span class="nocode">` から始まる行は実体参照変換せずに表示したい。
もしくは、`$content` を実体参照変換した後に `<span class="nocode">`~`</span>` の行を `htmlspecialchars_decode` する。

### 現状

`preg_replace_callback` で `$content` 内の文字列を抽出、置換

```
$content = preg_replace_callback(
  '/<pre(.*?)>(.+?)\<\/pre\>/s',
  function ($matchese){
    return htmlspecialchars($matchese[2], ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8');
  },
  $content
  );
```

`$content` を `var_dump` すると

```
string(131) "
&lt;?php
if($hoge == &#039;hogeho&#039;) {
  echo &#039;hoge&#039;;
}
&lt;span class=&quot;nocode&quot;&gt;nocode&lt;/span&gt;

?>"
```

と、中身を実体参照変換することができました。

`<span class="nocode"> 注釈 </span>` がソースコード内に入っていない場合はいいのですが、入っている場合のみ、 `<span class="nocode"> 注釈 </span>` の部分だけを変換したくありません。

この場合はどのようにしたらいいでしょうか？

ご回答お待ちしております。

Answer (score 1):

コールバック:

```
$content = preg_replace_callback(
    '/(<pre.*?>)(.+?)(<span.*?>.*?<\/span>.*)?(<\/pre\>)/s',
    function ($matchese) {
        $h = $matchese[1];
        $h .= htmlspecialchars($matchese[2], ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8');
        $h .= $matchese[3];
        $h .= $matchese[4];
        return $h;
    },
    $content
);

var_dump($content);
```

注釈あり入力:

```
<?php
$content = <<<'EOD'
<pre class="prettyprint linenums">
<?php
if($hoge == 'hoge') {
  echo 'hoge!';
}
<span class="nocode">text</span>
</pre>
?>
EOD;
```

注釈あり出力:

```
string(146) "<pre class="prettyprint linenums">
&lt;?php
if($hoge == &#039;hoge&#039;) {
  echo &#039;hoge!&#039;;
}
<span class="nocode">text</span>
</pre>
?>"
```

注釈なし入力：

```
<?php
$content = <<<'EOD'
<pre class="prettyprint linenums">
<?php
if($hoge == 'hoge') {
  echo 'hoge!';
}
</pre>
?>
EOD;
```

注釈なし出力:

```
string(114) "<pre class="prettyprint linenums">
&lt;?php
if($hoge == &#039;hoge&#039;) {
  echo &#039;hoge!&#039;;
}

</pre>
?>"
```